# Trim/whitespace issue when load data from Db2 source to Postgresql DB using Talend Open source

Tags: postgresql, etl, talend

We are seeing issue in table value which are populated from DB2 (source)  to Postgres (Target).
I have including here all the job details for each component.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Based on the above approach and once the data has been populated, when we run the below query in the Postgres DB.

```
SELECT * FROM VMRCTTA1.VMRRCUST_SUMM where cust_gssn_cd='XY03666699' ;
SELECT * FROM VMRCTTA1.VMRRCUST_SUMM where cust_cntry_cd='847' ;
```

There will be no records were returned however, when we run the same query with Trim as below it works.

```
SELECT * FROM VMRCTTA1.VMRRCUST_SUMM where trim(cust_gssn_cd)='XY03666699' ;
SELECT * FROM VMRCTTA1.VMRRCUST_SUMM where trim(cust_cntry_cd)='847' ;
```

Below are the ways we have tried to overcome this but no luck.

1. Used tmap between source and target component.
2. Used trim in source component under Advanced setting.
3. Change the datatype in Postgres DB of cust_cntry_cd from `char(5)` to `Character varying`, this will allow value without any length restriction.

Please suggest what is missing as we have this issue in almost all the table where we have `character/varchar` columns.

We are using TOS.

Answer (score 0):

The data type is probably `character(5)` in DB2.

That means that the trailing spaces are part of the column and will be migrated. You have to compare with

```
cust_cntry_cd = '847  '
```

or cast the right argument to `character(5)`:

```
cust_cntry_cd = CAST ('847' AS character(5))
```

Comment: It's not only with Character(5) , same issue is with Varchar data type and both source/target have same varhcar data type.

Comment: Do the `varchar`s affected by the problem contain trailing spaces in the DB2 database?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could delete all spaces in the advanced settings of the tDB2Input component.
Like the screen :

[image]

Comment: Also you can try to trim in the tmap with the trim function : StringHandling.TRIM(YourVariable)